# How many rows in a matrix do not contain a zero?

Tags: r, matrix

This is my matrix in R:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    5    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    5
 [3,]    0    2    3
 [4,]    1    2    2
 [5,]    5    0    0
 [6,]    1    4    0
 [7,]    4    1    0
 [8,]    0    0    5
 [9,]    1    2    2
[10,]    3    2    0
[11,]    4    0    1

mat <- structure(c(5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(11L, 3L))
```

I need find how many rows do not contain a zero, in this case the answer is 2:

- the 4th row (1,2,2)
- the 9th row, also(1,2,2)

Is there is a command for this or should I make a routine? I tried with two `for()` loops, but it's bad.

Comment: Please post data, not screenshot.

Comment: sorry, I do not know

Comment: @albert - like my edit. Use `dput(mat)` to get data that people here can then copy and paste.

Comment: It's a pretty common question. `sum( rowSums(mat==0) == 0 )` is one way. Run in parts `mat==0` and `rowSums(mat==0)` and so on to see how it works and look at the help page `?rowSums`. The sum of a TRUE/FALSE vector is the number of TRUEs.

Comment: @Frank would people get mad at this? : ) `sum(!rowSums(mat==0))`

Comment: @PierreLafortune Looks okay to me. A matter of preference / familiarity, I think. Also `sum(!rowSums(!mat))`, no?

Comment: A matter of being able to type less and a good lesson on coercion. I thought I had a birdie, eagle right there : )

Answer (score 1):

quick answer:

```
sum( 0 < apply(mat,1,prod) )
```

also:

```
nonzerorows <- 0 < apply(mat,1,prod)     # logical selector of rows
mat[ nonzerorows, ]
mat[!nonzerorows, ]
which(nonzerorows)
sum(nonzerorows)
```

OP's data:

```
mat <- structure(c(5L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 
2L, 2L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
5L, 2L, 0L, 1L), .Dim = c(11L, 3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mat <- matrix(sample(0:4, 16, replace=T), 4, 4)
mat
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4    1    2    2
# [2,]    3    3    1    1
# [3,]    1    2    4    4
# [4,]    0    4    4    4
apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(x!=0))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
which(apply(mat, 1, function(x) all(x!=0)))
# [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach, e.g. when you're concerned about other numbers or elements could be this:
`sum(apply(mat,1,function(x) {0 %in% x == F}))`